# Android application: RecyclerView hangs when I put around 300 records from API in it at one go

Tags: java, android, api

I have a android application in which I am getting around 200 to 1000 records from an API and displaying it in RecyclerView, the UI hangs a bit as I load all data in RecyclerView in one go and I know infinite scrolling is the solution but, do I need to change TRest API to fetch only few data with limit and call it again n again with user scrolling down or load data in one go and add in recyclerView as user scrolls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to implement pagination. Load a limited data and load remainig data in onscroll. It's the right way to load huge records of data in recycler view.

Comment: Yeah that's my confusion, how to load limited data do I have to change API code for that and fetch data with limit. As API code is hard to change as its been used in  many other places, so can't do it.

Comment: if its hard to change the Api, then you have to manually change your java code to make adjustments. Instead of fetching whole array make a limit and fetch. after the limit make a progress and fetch the data again starting from limit.But it is not the right way.